# How to set multiple properties of a java annotation with xtend (using xbase)

Tags: java, annotations, xtext, xtend, xbase

According to [the JvmTypesBuilder documentation](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.3/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/jvmmodel/JvmTypesBuilder.html#toAnnotation%28org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29), I use need to use `toAnnotation(EObject sourceElement, Class type, Object value)`

I do not understand what value I should put there? Because I have an annotation w

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface OResultInfo {
    String rowNames() default "";
    String columnNames() default "";
    String keyNames() default "";
}
```

I have absolutely no idea how to to set these values. Maybe there is something about java annotations I do not know/understand?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
val jvmAnnotation = toAnnotation(EObject sourceElement, Class type)
```

And create and add annotation values per value and assign it to the jvmAnnotationReference:

```
val annotationValue = TypesFactory.eInstance.createJvmStringAnnotationValue();
annotationValue.getValues().add(value);
annotationValue.setOperation(annotationTypesOperation); //i.e. the JvmOperation representing rowNames(), columnNames() or keyNames()
jvmAnnotation.getValues().add(annotationValue);
```